# Stream from pc to android throw java sockets, it's possible or may use RTP or http?

Tags: java, android, sockets, streaming, rtp

I try a project in which I want to stream media from my java application which is running in my pc to my android app and vice versa.In my first try  I believe that I can make a tcp or udp connection and stream bytes from pc app to the android app. But not find how to do it,  is there any way for doing this?I stream the bytes, but not find solution for mediaplayer to play from received bytes.

My second try was to have two threads in android app, one reads media bytes from socket and writes to an temporary file and a second thread which uses mediaplayer to play this temp file but nothing...

I also try to have the media file into an apache http server that I have to my pc and try to feed the mediaplayer with the http url, like http://my-computer-ip-addres/media.mp4 and works. So, it's a good solution to try to make an embedded http server to streams the file from my java application to the android phone or use the httpserver api.

Also there is the rtp/rstp method, but I'm so new in streaming and I don't know if I can create an rtp server, to streaming the media.It's very hard to do this?I think that will be the best solution, but I don't know how to do it, and from where to start. If anyone can help me, suggest some resource like tutorial, a book.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a pre-made streaming server such as Red 5?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer and sorry for my late response.. I see that red 5 is a flash streaming server. So I must use j2ee and an application server to server the flash streaming? I want to stream between the two java applications direct. Can  I do this with red 5?

Comment: I'm not expert with red5, only lightly familiar with it.  It is written in java (not flash) and streams several audio and video formats as flash.   I suppose that does not exactly meet your requirements - though the server is a java application, it expects the client to be a flash client - which Android now has, but wouldn't be very suited for you making a custom android app as the client.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: You need to break the image into packets and send over through socket class provided by java; and rebuild it on the other side of the application to display the image. This works for almost all video stream between two devices. However, there may be shortcut between PC to android.

will

Comment: What exactly you mean, If I understand correctly you mean to extract pictures from the video(on pc) and send it to the android phone and display it in the correct frame rate?